# jQueryMobile and datebox plugin with dynamic fields

Tags: jquery, plugins, mobile, datebox

Using JQueryMobile final release and the jquery.mobile.datebox.js plugin.  On the pageshow event I am adding a series of fields dynamically, some of these are date/time fields using the datebox plugin.  Everything works fine except on smaller devices and iPhone in particular (it also happens with desktop browsers when you make them particularly narrow).  When you click on the date or time icon the helper pops up, I can select a date/time and it goes into the field but the field then gets duplicated along with anything else in the .

Here's an example of the page show code.  It calls a webservice to get json data back that defined the fields that should be added to the form.  The fields can be date, radio or text.  It all works fine except the redrawing of the date/time fields after the popup:

```
$('#editthing').live('pageshow', function (e, info) {
    var listurl = "/editthingattribute";
    //Add a cache 'buster' parameter
    var date = new Date();
    listurl = listurl + '?p_uid=' + date.getTime();
    $.ajax({
        url: listurl + "&p_id=" + getUrlVar("p_id") + "&p_thingattribute=" + getUrlVar("p_thingattribute"),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var form = $("#formcontent");
            form.html = "";
            //Add the fields defined in the results from the database call
            $.each(data.editthingfields, function (index, item) {
                //Set the global field type
                fieldType = item.fieldType;

                if (item.fieldtype == 'date') {
                    inputType = 'date';

                    //This messes up on narrow browsers
                    form.append('<div data-role="fieldcontain">' + '<label for="' + item.fieldname + '_date">' + item.fieldlabel + ' (Date)</label>' + '<input name="' + item.fieldname + '_date" id="' + item.fieldname + '_date" ' + 'type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options=\'{"mode": "calbox", "dateFormat":"dd/mm/YYYY"}\' ' + 'value="' + item.fieldvalue.substring(0, 10) + '" />' + '</div>' + '<div data-role="fieldcontain">' + '<label for="' + item.fieldname + '_time">' + item.fieldlabel + ' (Time)</label>' + '<input name="' + item.fieldname + '_time" id="' + item.fieldname + '_time" ' + 'type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options=\'{"mode": "timebox"}\' ' + 'value="' + item.fieldvalue.substring(11, 17) + '" />' + '</div>');
                } else if (item.fieldtype == 'radio') {
                    inputType = 'radio';
                    //Add a suitable set of radio buttons for the attribute being edited.
                    form.append('<div data-role="fieldcontain">' + '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">' + '<legend>' + item.fieldlabel + '</legend>');
                    var optionsarray = item.fieldoptions.split(',');
                    for (var i = 0; i < optionsarray.length; i++) {
                        if (item.fieldvalue == optionsarray[i]) {
                            form.append('<input name="' + item.fieldname + '" id="' + optionsarray[i] + '" ' + 'type="' + item.fieldtype + '" value="' + optionsarray[i] + '" checked="checked" />');
                        } else {
                            form.append('<input name="' + item.fieldname + '" id="' + optionsarray[i] + '" ' + 'type="' + item.fieldtype + '" value="' + optionsarray[i] + '" />');
                        }
                        form.append('<label for="' + optionsarray[i] + '">' + optionsarray[i] + '</label>');
                    }
                    form.append('</fieldset>' + '</div>');
                } else {
                    inputType = 'text';
                    form.append('<div data-role="fieldcontain">' + '<label for="' + item.fieldname + '">' + item.fieldlabel + '</label>' + '<input name="' + item.fieldname + '" id="' + item.fieldname + '" ' + 'type="' + item.fieldtype + '" value="' + item.fieldvalue + '" />' + '</div>');
                }
            });
            var thinghdr = $("#thingheader");
            thinghdr.html = "";
            $(data.thingdetails).each(function (index) {
                thinghdr.append("<h3>" + this.thingoper + " " + this.thingnumber + " " + this.thingdesc + "</h3>");
            });

            $("#editthing").page("destroy").page();
        }
    });
});
```

I'm guessing the problem is due to the fields being added dynamically but I don't know how to get round it.

thanks in advance
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You might have moved on past this, but I have found that the jQuery mobile way of updating elements is to call create on them. Perhaps it will help you have the behavior you're interested in intsead of `page("destroy").page();`

After I append my dynamic element into being, I call trigger("create") on it like this:

```
$(".selector").append(elementToAppend).trigger("create");
```

This is from the jQuery mobile documentation page [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html).

> **Enhancing new markup**
>
> The page plugin dispatches a pageInit event,
> which most widgets use to auto-initialize themselves. As long as a
> widget plugin script is referenced, it will automatically enhance any
> instances of the widgets it finds on the page.
>
> However, if you generate new markup client-side or load in content via
> Ajax and inject it into a page, you can trigger the create event to
> handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within
> the new markup. This can be triggered on any element (even the page
> div itself), saving you the task of manually initializing each plugin
> (listview button, select, etc.).
>
> For example, if a block of HTML markup (say a login form) was loaded
> in through Ajax, trigger the create event to automatically transform
> all the widgets it contains (inputs and buttons in this case) into the
> enhanced versions. The code for this scenario would be:
>
> $( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page"
> ).trigger( "create" );